# Using Xcode for generic C/C++ development

Tags: xcode, configuration, refactoring

I'd like to use all the power of Xcode for generic C/C++ projects but I can't figure out what are the basic steps to configure a new Xcode project and *attach* it to an existing source tree of a legacy, plain, C/C++ project.

Creating a new empty project, attaching it to a source tree and configuring a build target (using GNU Make) was a really silly task.

I can't figure out how to enable source code indexing in order to enable source refactoring tools, searching and fast-jumping and all the amenities that makes the Xcode programmer's life great.
Moreover I'd like to use the internal debugging facilities…

Does anyone point me to a tutorial, a hint or whatever could be useful?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a (dirty) path to enable refactoring tools:

I've added a new standard «console target» to the project and added all the source files under the Build Phases > Compiled Sources.

Refactoring tools now works. Having two targets doesn't seem to be a relevant issue (elegance apart)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't attempt to use legacy Makefiles, even though I think there's some support for that.

Typically what I do with a traditional C/C++ project is to store my XCode project folder at the root of the project. So it might look like:

```
--myApp
  --src
  --inc
  --myApp Xcode
```

I then drag the src folder and inc folder into the project navigator. This gives me an Xcode project to compile with on the Mac, and then I have the traditional Makefile for compiling on Linux (actually, I prefer CMake for other platforms, but either way works).

Comment: Yes, clean approach. In any case Make works perfectly with Xcode building system.